# XSLT: Concatenating the text of an XML file collection

Tags: xml, xslt

I build a text string that concatenates all the text found in a collection of XML files, using:

```
 <xsl:variable name="text-accumulated">
        <xsl:for-each select="collection($collection-string)">
                <xsl:copy-of select="//concat(text()[1], ' ')"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:variable>
```

Note: concat'ing the space prevented words from merging around some of the carriage returns (or linefeeds).

**Result**

It's working for me. But I am always wary of using `//`.

I'm also aware that the results of a *deep copy* done by `copy-of` can sometimes surprise you. I had used `value-of` and received identical results.

Is there a better way to merge all the text in a file collection?

Does a built-in function exist that I should be using instead (IRT, Saxon 9.5)?

Is `value-of` a better option than `copy-of`?

Comment: Does `<xsl:variable name="text-accumulated" select="string-join(collection($collection-string), ' ')"/>` not suffice? As for deep copies, do you want to create any nodes at all? It looks as if you simply want a string value.

Comment: Martin, it's not bringing up the desired result, but I'll work on it--it is certainly more concise code. Good hint on the copy-of: that may bring in errant node(), value-of would not.

Comment: Your `select="//concat(text()[1], ' ')"` on the `xsl:copy-of` is computing strings anyway  and that way would rather work like an `xsl:sequence`. It might help if you post three or four snippets of sample documents where you want to concatenate the text or string value, plus the desired result, then it is easier for us to tell what you want to achieve and to suggest alternatives. `//concat(text()[1], ' ')` looks that unusual to me that I am not sure what you want to compute with it, without seeing some samples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `<xsl:copy-of select="//concat(text()[1], ' ')"/>`

This instruction **actually doesn't copy the complete text** of an XML document!

Here is an example:

```
<a>
  <b>X1<c>Y</c>X2</b>
</a>
```

When the above XML document is processed with the following transformation (which includes just the XSLT instruction from the provided code):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy-of select="//concat(text()[1], ' ')"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the result is:

```
  X1    Y
```

As we see, the string "`X2`" is not present in the output.

Another problem is, that it is not possible to identify which exactly spaces were added as delimiters between any two text nodes.

In other words, the produced output is not exactly the concatenation of the text-nodes of the XML documents.

In case you aren't concerned with the latter problem, one correct XPath 2.0 expression that joins all text nodes in a document using space as the delimiter is:

```
//string-join(text(), ' ')
```

With this correction, your provided code becomes:

```
 <xsl:variable name="text-accumulated">
        <xsl:for-each select="collection($collection-string)">
                <xsl:copy-of select="//string-join(text(), ' ')"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:variable>
```

> Is `value-of` a better option than `copy-of`?

It is not correct to compare which of these two XSLT instructions is "better", because they serve different goals.

```
<xsl:value-of>
```

produces a single text node whose string value is the concatenation of the string values of the selected items (possibly separated by a separator-string, if the `separator` attribute is specified.

On the other side,

```
<xsl:copy-of>
```

produces a copy of a sequence of nodes and/or atomic values, with each new node containing copies of all the children, attributes, and (by default) namespaces of the original node, recursively.

It is obvious that the two instructions are not mutually replaceable and each can be used to solve a different problem.

> It's working for me. But I am always wary of using `//`

One can use **patterns** instead of absolute expressions. In your case something like this:

```
 <xsl:variable name="text-accumulated">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="collection($collection-string)" mode="mergeText"/>
 </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="text()" mode="mergeText">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(., ' ')"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: An outstanding and educational answer.. thank you. A minor quibble on your first point regarding "not catching all" ---with my XML, it did. In any case, your reply was great. And a hat-tip to Martin H for his salient comments.

Comment: @Paulb, You are welcome. You can find this Pluralsight video-training course, which covers both XPath 2.0 and XSLT 2.0: http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/xslt-foundations-part1